# Python : How to call a global function from a imported module

Tags: python, namespaces

Would it be possible to call a global function from imported function in Python 3?

./folders/folder1/def.py

```
def do_test():
  print("++ def.do_test()")
  global_function_1()
  print("-- def.do_test()")
```

./main.py

```
import importlib

def global_function_1():
  print("doing function 1 thing...")

mod = importlib.import_module('folders.folder1.def')
mod.do_test()
```

I have the error like this.

```
++ def.do_test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\src\python\class2\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    mod.do_test()
  File "C:\src\python\class2\folders\folder1\def.py", line 4, in do_test
    global_function_1()
NameError: name 'global_function_1' is not defined
```

Apparently, the same functions works just fine if defined in the same file.

```
def global_function_1():
  print("calling the global function 1")


def do_test():
  print("++ def.do_test()")
  global_function_1()
  print("-- def.do_test()")

do_test()
```

The results is

```
++ def.do_test()
calling the global function 1
-- def.do_test()
```

If Python doesn't allow this, what would be the closest alternative ?
In my real project, the global functions has number of accesses to the global
variables. If all the possible, I'd like to avoid putting all the global functions
and variables in a separate class.

EDIT : The above is the code excerpt to highlight my problem. In my real project,

1. I have dozen of global functions. So, passing its pointer through function parameter is not preffered.
2. I have dozen of other def.py files in multiple folders. I need to pick up the def.py file at run-time depending on variety conditions. So, static reference from main.py to def.py is not preffered.

Comment: Anything wrong with adding `from main import global_function_1` to `def.py`?

Comment: There's no classes in the code in your question, so how does it all relate to the "from a class" in the title of your question?

Comment: @Rawing -- Thank you for your advise. I put my result in SmeltQuake's answer below, who gave me the same advise.

Comment: @martineau --- You are right. I mixed up with another type of implementation. I jsut corrected the subject. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get`main.py`to work with the following set-up.

(Note I had to add an empty`__init__.py`files to both the`folders`and`folder1`subdirectories to get the imports to work.)

File **`.\class2\folders\folder1\def.py`**

```
from main import global_function_1

def do_test():
    print("++ def.do_test()")
    global_function_1()
    print("-- def.do_test()")
```

File **`.\class2\main.py`**

```
import importlib

def global_function_1():
    print("doing function 1 thing...")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mod = importlib.import_module('folders.folder1.def')
    mod.do_test()
```

Output:

```
++ def.do_test()
doing function 1 thing...
-- def.do_test()
```

Comment: Thank you ! Yes, it works in my environment, too. I found "if __name__ == '__main__':" is also necessary to make it work, in addition to the empty __init__.py files.

Comment: Yeah, it's an unusual situation, `main.py` imports something that imports it -- which is why the `if __name__ == '__main__':` is needed. I'm surprised though that it doesn't go into an infinite import loop without it...

Answer (score 1):

What you created is called a module. It can't be used if it's not imported to the file it's used in. In your case, def.py needs to import main.

Importing can be done like this:

```
from moduleFilename import moduleFunctionname
```

you can then do

```
moduleFunctionname()
```

Alternative:

```
import moduleFilename
moduleFilename.moduleFunctionname()
```

EDIT: Seems like Rawing was faster with his comment...

Comment: I tried it, but resulted in another failure.

    File "C:\src\python\class2\folders\folder1\def.py", line 1, in <module> import main
    File "C:\src\python\class2\main.py", line 8, in <module> mod.do_test()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'do_test'

Comment: Could you maybe post your updated code? You probably either imported it in the wrong file or misspelled it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Wait, I think i can see what you meant. Delete the first and last two lines of code from the main.py you posted, I think the importlib doesn't fit what you want to do. Then add the "import main" in the def.py and access your functions by typing "main.<functionName>() in def.py. Here's the docs on the topic: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Thank you for the further comment. But I don't know other option than importlib, to import files dynamically ( in other words, I change the files to import, depending on the input, in real project ). So, I need to stay with importlib, unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `folders.folder1.def` independent of back-importing stuff, as it seems like something as a library or plugin or such, you can resort to getting it as a callback:

library:

```
def do_test(callback):
  print("++ def.do_test()")
  callback()
  print("-- def.do_test()")
```

main module:

```
import importlib

def global_function_1():
  print("doing function 1 thing...")

mod = importlib.import_module('folders.folder1.def')
mod.do_test(global_function_1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes, this works. But this isn't scalable when I have dozen of global function in my real project.